# Безопасность экранирования через PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Использую PDO, и подготовленные запросы.
Но вот суть такова, что к примеру мне приходить сообщение из поля ввода типа textarea

```
лалала, привер всем!
\n (это перенос строки когда в textarea происходит enter)
я юзер который отправил смс!
```

**Так вот в чем суть, безопасно ли вставлять сразу PDO подготовленный запрос, содержимое которое пришло от юзера, напрямую?**

Сейчас использую кучу регулярных выражений, на проверку содержимого, но многие жалуются, что мол форма выдает ошибки типо "ПОле заполнено не правильно", и каждый раз дописывать, вырезать из форм всякие UNION, SELECT и т.д надоело...

Comment: я думаю что нормально, но вот когда будешь выводить эти сообщения, то экранируй их

Comment: Но я использую $pdo->prepare(); , а в sql запросе плейсхолдеры, оно само экранирует же, в этом то и фишка

Comment: Значит безопасно, на то они и есть подготовленные запромы

Comment: Это получается, что в sql запрос можно на прямую из поля ввода пользователя вставлять данные, но все не советуют, вот поэтому и задал вопрос такой..

Из документации:
вызов PDO::prepare() .... а также помогает избежать SQL инъекций, так как нет необходимости экранировать передаваемые параметры.

Comment: во всяком случае никогда нельзя доверять пользователям

Comment: В этом то и дело, вы используете экранирование напрямую?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У тебя несколько противоречивые заявления. В вопросе ты пишешь:

> безопасно ли вставлять сразу PDO подготовленный запрос, содержимое которое пришло от юзера, напрямую?

Это не совсем по-русски, но можно понять так, что ты подставляешь в запрос те данные, которые пришли от юзера. Разумеется, так делать нельзя.

Однако в комментариях ты пишешь, что

> Но я использую $pdo->prepare(); , а в sql запросе плейсхолдеры,

То есть, ты не подставляешь ничего в запрос напрямую. Но потом опять:

> Это получается, что в sql запрос можно на прямую из поля ввода пользователя вставлять данные, но все не советуют,

Ты уже определись - подставляешь ты что-то в запрос напрямую, или нет.

Если данные *действительно* подставляются в запрос напрямую, например так:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = '{$_GET['email']}'");
$stmt->execute();
```

то такой запрос, разумеется, **небезопасен**.

Но если используются плейсхолдеры, например

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT name FROM users WHERE email = ?');
$stmt->execute([$_GET['email']]);
```

то здесь **данные не подставляются напрямую в запрос**, что делает его **безопасным**.

Comment: Достаточно ли безопасно вставлять так данные в запрос? Через плейсхолдеры....

Comment: Если бы было небезопасно, то в них не было бы смысла